# When updating, what does Windows (10) do with my user folder?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, multi-boot, data-recovery, updates

My computer has an gpt disk with Ubuntu Desktop (for general work) and Windows 10 (for xbox dev) on two separate partitions.
Last night I shutdown windows and left it installing updates. This morning I came in, powered it on and it did that thing where it finishes the update process. It got to about 25% complete and then rebooted (as is normal while updating); However, upon reboot I was greeted with a quick flash of console output "couldn't find /boot/" or something similar, followed by the Grub2 terminal. I tried all the fixes I could find through Google and here (boot-repair, manual boot...), and settled on just backing up my data and wiping the disk.

And therein lies my problem:
I booted ubuntu off a usb stick, popped open a terminal and `cd`'d to the Users directory. According to `ll` only contents were `All Users`, `Default`(all folders empty) and `Public`. No trace of my own user folder.
I had not moved the folder inside windows, I had left the settings as default.

**Is my data gone? Is there any way to find/recover it?**

EDIT: Solved the problem using a linux terminal: `find / -iname "<any file/pattern in old user folder>`. Turns out windows puts the user folder in `Windows.old` when updating.

Answer (score -1):

When windows does an update, it moves the folders in `C:\Users` (in addition to many other things) to the `C:\Windows.old` directory.

If the update fails, then the old user folders can be found there.